# Linuxcontainers » LXC : Security Vulnerabilities

Tags: linux, container

I have a question regarding Linuxcontainers. How do you classify the security vulnerability mentioned [here](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-13134/product_id-27105/Linuxcontainers-LXC.html), more specifically the ones that ends with 6441,1331,1134,1335 and 10124.

I mean are they a guest to the host and the internet to host type of attack or what exactly ?